# Fokker Planck equation with known potential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve the following problem for 4 days by hand but I failed:( Could anyone help me to solve it? I want to know if Mathematica has some inability to solve it or not?

$$\frac{\partial P(x,t)}{\partial t}  =- \frac{\partial J(x,t)}{\partial x}$$

$$J = \left[\cos(kx)+0.5\cos(2kx)+A\sin(wt)-D\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right] P(x,t)$$

This is the code I used:

```
pde = D[y[x, t], t] + D[j, x] - d D[(Cos[x] + 0.5 Cos[2 x] + A Sin[w t]) y[x, t], x, x] == 0
sol = DSolve[{pde, y[x, 0] == DiracDelta[x]}, y[x, t], {x, t}]
```

Comment: This is a PDE. Did you read the [tutorial on PDEs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/SolveAPartialDifferentialEquation.html)? What did you try? It seems like the [Method of lines](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html)  will be a good fit here.

Comment: I need analytical solution

Comment: Your Mathematica code does not correspond to the equations you give in MathJaX form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for the PDE you gave does not correspond to your equation, as mentioned by @m_goldberg.  Here is a code for your PDE:

```
j[x_, t_] := (Cos[x] + 0.5 Cos[2 x] + A Sin[w t]) y[x, t] - 
   d*D[y[x, t], x];
pde = D[y[x, t], t] + D[j[x, t], x] == 0
```

Mma, however, cannot solve this equation analytically. Think about looking for a numerical solution.